# How to Debug on the Samsung Galaxy I7500 Android Phone

Tags: android, debugging, device

How to Debug on the Samsung Galaxy I7500 Android Phone?

modify `c:\android-sdk-windows-1.5_r3\usb_driver\x86\android_usb.inf`

under the [Google.NTx86] entry add

```
; SAMSUNG GALAXY
%USB\VID_04E8&PID_6640.DeviceDescRelease%=androidusb.Dev, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6640
%USB\VID_04E8&PID_6640&MI_04.DeviceDescRelease%=androidusb.Dev, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6640&MI_04
%USB\VID_04E8&PID_6640.DeviceDescRelease%=androidusb.Dev, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6640
```

under the [Strings] entry add

```
; SAMSUNG GALAXY
USB\VID_04E8&PID_6640.DeviceDescRelease="SAMSUNG GALAXY"
USB\VID_04E8&PID_6640&MI_04.DeviceDescRelease="SAMSUNG GALAXY Composite ADB Interface"
USB\VID_04E8&PID_6640.DeviceDescRelease="SAMSUNG GALAXY Bootloader"
```

Some people have reported the MI_04 combination above is not working; you may want to try `MI_1` to `MI_4` to be sure.

4. go to the phone `-> Settings -> Applications -> Development -> enable USB debugging`
5. Windows will ask for a new driver - this is used for debugging. Point the driver search to `c:\android-sdk-windows-1.5_r3\usb_driver\x86\`.

When i followed the above steps system tried to install driver and then prompt  following error.
[image]

Reference URL: http://adrianvintu.com/blogengine/post/How-to-Debug-on-the-Samsung-Galaxy-I7500-Android-Phone.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following ADB works 100%

http://www.yardimage.co.uk/files/i7500/samsungADB.zip